# Android - AudioRecord class does not read data, audioData and fftArray return zero

Tags: android, fft, audiorecord

I am new to android and I have been working on a Pitch Analyzer application (minimum SDK: 8). I read many articles on how to implement Audiorecord class but I wonder why it does not read any data when I record. I tried to display the values of the audioData and fftArray but zero is returned, so I assumed the problem is with the read method. Please try to check these. Here are the codes I used:

[FFT.java](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/97data/FFT.java)
 [Complex.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html)

**record.java**

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("pitch.analyzer.PitZer.ASSESSMENT");
MediaRecorder recorder;
AudioRecord tuner;
int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
int sampleRateInHz = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
int bufferSizeInBytes = 4096;

int samples;
short[] audioBuffer;
short[] audioData;
double[] temp;
TextView fft;
TextView results;
//TextView bufferSize;
Complex[] fftTempArray;
Complex[] fftArray;
Complex[] fftInverse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.record);

    Button start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.record);
    Button stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    fft = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fft);
    results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
    //bufferSize = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bufferSize);     
    audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];
    tuner = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSizeInBytes);
    //final AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/temp");

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            acquire();
            computeFFT();
            display();
        }
    });       

    //â€¦.wait a while

        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
}
public void acquire(){
    try {
        tuner.startRecording();
        samples = tuner.read(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
    }
    catch (Throwable t){

    }   
}

public void computeFFT(){
    //Conversion from short to double
    double[] micBufferData = new double[bufferSizeInBytes];//size may need to change
    final int bytesPerSample = 2; // As it is 16bit PCM
    final double amplification = 100.0; // choose a number as you like
    for (int index = 0, floatIndex = 0; index < bufferSizeInBytes - bytesPerSample + 1; index += bytesPerSample, floatIndex++) {
        double sample = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
            int v = audioData[index + b];
            if (b < bytesPerSample - 1 || bytesPerSample == 1) {
                v &= 0xFF;
            }
            sample += v << (b * 8);
        }
        double sample32 = amplification * (sample / 32768.0);
        micBufferData[floatIndex] = sample32;
    }

    //Create Complex array for use in FFT
    fftTempArray = new Complex[bufferSizeInBytes];
    for (int i=0; i<bufferSizeInBytes; i++)
    {
        fftTempArray[i] = new Complex(micBufferData[i], 0);
    }

    //Obtain array of FFT data
    fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);
    fftInverse = FFT.ifft(fftTempArray);
    double[] freq2 = new double[fftArray.length];
    //Create an array of magnitude of fftArray
    double[] magnitude = new double[fftArray.length];
    for (int i=0; i<fftArray.length; i++){
        magnitude[i]= fftArray[i].abs();
        freq2[i] = ComputeFrequency(magnitude[i]);
    }

    fft.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    //fft.setText("fftArray is "+ fftArray[500] +" and fftTempArray is "+fftTempArray[500] + " and fftInverse is "+fftInverse[500]+" and audioData is "+audioData[500]+ " and magnitude is "+ magnitude[1] + ", "+magnitude[500]+", "+magnitude[1000]+ " and freq2 is "+ freq2[1]+" You rock dude!");
    /*for(int i = 2; i < samples; i++){
        fft.append(" " + magnitude[i] + " Hz");
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < samples; i++){
        fft.append(" " + freq2[i] + " Hz");
    }
    */
}

private double ComputeFrequency(double arrayIndex) {
    return ((1.0 * sampleRateInHz) / (1.0 * 100)) * arrayIndex;
    }

public void display(){
    results.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    results.setText("results: "+audioData[1]+"");
    for(int i = 2; i < samples; i++){
        results.append(" " + audioData[i]);
    }
    results.invalidate();
    //fft.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    fft.setText("sampleRateInHz: "+sampleRateInHz);
    fft.append("\nfftArray: "+fftArray[0]+" Hz");
    for(int i = 1; i < samples; i++){
        fft.append(" " + fftArray[i] + " Hz");
        }
    fft.append("\naudioData: "+audioData[1]);
    fft.append("\nsamples: "+samples);
    //fft.invalidate();
}
public void stop() throws IOException {
    tuner.stop();
    //audioInput.reset();
    tuner.release();

    //recorder.stop();
    //recorder.reset();
    //recorder.release();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Before reading from the device you should start a recording(and stop it once you finish).
Here is the code i use for a simple read:

```
 short[] audioData = new short[bufferSize];

 int offset =0;
 int shortRead = 0;

 //start tapping into the microphone
 audioRecored.startRecording();

 //start reading from the microphone to an internal buffer - chuck by chunk
 while (offset < bufferSize)
 {
    shortRead = audioRecored.read(audioData, offset ,bufferSize - offset);
        offset += shortRead;
 }

 //stop tapping into the microphone
 audioRecored.stop();
```

Comment: don't forget to add `audioRecord.release()` too.

Answer (score 1):

Also check if microphone is used only once, in application.
All devices before version 23, does not allow nonblocking reading of microphone stream.
If there are two processes reading from microphone stream only first one is getting real data.
Other returns -2, or -3 (read count) as an exception to read blocked stream.