# how to compute frequency and detect pitch of a compressed (mp3) audio file? - Android

Tags: android, compression, pitch, frequency-analysis

I'm having a 
[problem with recording audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742259/android-audiorecord-class-does-not-read-data-audiodata-and-fftarray-return-ze%22problem%20with%20recording%20audio%22) using Audiorecord class because the data returned is always zero (the read method does not record audio).

So, I thought of playing a compressed audio and read it for processing or decompressing. How could it be possible? I would like to compute the frequency of the audio file. I really need your help.