# Android - .read() method

Tags: android, audiorecord

I' m trying to read recorded data into the short array. I want to continue recording and reading until it is full. My code: 
http://pastebin.com/r6yuPn82 
Unfortunately applications crashes after calling startRecording method. Errors:
http://pastebin.com/9jwrPLNc
May I kindly ask you to help me fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AudioRecord hasn't been initialized correctly.

"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an **uninitialized AudioRecord**."

Put this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not crashing anymore. However I checked content of my short array and it's filled with zeros. What I did wrong?

Comment: In the documentary [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) it says:  
`public int read (ByteBuffer audioBuffer, int sizeInBytes)`
"Added in API level 3

Reads audio data from the audio hardware for recording into a direct buffer. If this buffer is not a direct buffer, this method will always return 0."

I think you need a ByteBuffer instead of your short Array.

Comment: According to the documentary I can also use short type: read(short[] audioData, int offsetInShorts, int sizeInShorts)
Reads audio data from the audio hardware for recording into a buffer.

Comment: I'm using 16-bit PCM so every sample needs 2 bytes.

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake. I currently have no idea, sorry :/ 
Maybe ask this in a new question so it gets some more attention.
But maybe the first answer of this question helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707994/android-audiorecord-questions)

Comment: I tried to use ByteBuffer first and then copy data into byte array but it's still filled with zeros :/ Anyway thank you for your help, at least I can try to do something now instead of having my app crashed every time.

Comment: @Siggy, did you post a new question on this somewhere? I'm having an issue where the shorts I read into the buffer are all 0 (zero) so I'd like to see if you solved this.

Comment: I solved the "all zero" problem by changing my inputs -- I was not using the microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're recording before you read from your MIC to the buffer.

See answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742259/android-audiorecord-class-does-not-read-data-audiodata-and-fftarray-return-ze) saying the the following:

```
 short[] audioData = new short[bufferSize];

 int offset =0;
 int shortRead = 0;

 //start tapping into the microphone
 audioRecored.startRecording();

 //start reading from the microphone to an internal buffer - chuck by chunk
 while (offset < bufferSize)
 {
    shortRead = audioRecored.read(audioData, offset ,bufferSize - offset);
        offset += shortRead;
 }

 //stop tapping into the microphone
 audioRecored.stop();
```